# Google fonts with shopify polaris Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, shopify-app, google-fonts

I'm having trouble changing fonts of shopify polaris.
In my `styles.css` I have this:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo");
.App {
  font-family: Archivo;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

And in my `index.js` I have this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppProvider>
        <Button>Test Button</Button>
      </AppProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I also `import './styles.css'` in index.js. Here is the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/98kmj283lp. It's really small and simple. If anyone can help me do this, that'd be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you type some text in the body outside of the `Button` you'll see that your font change is actually having an effect.

However, I don't think you're supposed to change the fonts neither of text, nor of `Button` or any other component in a Shopify app. The whole purpose of Polaris framework is to make things look the same. Also, I wouldn't change the font of normal text.

See the guidelines here: https://polaris.shopify.com/design/typography#section-font-stack

Answer (score 0):

here's my solution.

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo:400");

.App {
  font-family: 'Archivo', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: center;
}
```